# Group by the Sub-Query which is derived from WITH CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting error for my below query, while I'm trying to grouping the sub-query. I built the sub-query using the WITH Clause.

Please correct me

```
WITH Student AS (SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE SEX='M')
SELECT NAME, AGE, STATUS, SUM(TOTAL)
(SELECT 
NAME, 
'15' AS AGE,
CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE > 50 AND ATTENDANCE  < 60 THEN 'GOOD' 
WHEN ATTENDANCE > 60 'GREAT'
ELSE 'BAD' END AS STATUS
SUM (MARK) AS TOTAL
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY NAME, ATTENDANCE ) A
GROUP BY NAME, AGE, STATUS
```

Error: `SQL Query not properly ended`

Comment: tl;dr you actually need to group by _exactly_ what is in the SELECT statement, i.e. the CASE statement itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `from` clause:

```
WITH Student AS (SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE SEX='M')
SELECT NAME, AGE, STATUS, SUM(TOTAL)
FROM (SELECT NAME, '15' AS AGE,
             (CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE > 50 AND ATTENDANCE  < 60 THEN 'GOOD' 
                   WHEN ATTENDANCE > 60 'GREAT'
                   ELSE 'BAD'
              END) AS STATUS,
             SUM(MARK) AS TOTAL
      FROM STUDENT
      GROUP BY NAME, ATTENDANCE
     ) A
GROUP BY NAME, AGE, STATUS
```

The query is much longer than it needs to be to achieve the output you want, but this seems to be the problem you have.